# Issue with unique ( symbolic ) in octave

Tags: unique, octave

i am using Octave 6.2 on Windows 10 Pro.
The following two codesnippets speak for themself:

```
syms a b;
 unique([a,b])
 ans = (sym) [a  b]  (1x2 matrix)
```

So long, so good.

But

```
unique([a])
error: Python exception: UnboundLocalError: local variable 's' referenced before assignment
occurred at line 1 of the Python code block:
return sp.Matrix([list(uniq(*_ins))]),
error: called from
pycall_sympy__ at line 178 column 7
unique at line 55 column 5
```

I've done a ugly workaround, but of course it slows down the computation time.
Have anyone the same issue?
Any suggestions?

Comment: On octave 6.1.1 I get an error at `syms a b;` so I can't help you... (The issue I have is specifically https://github.com/cbm755/octsympy/issues/1035)

Comment: What was your ugly workaround? If it's just checking length first, I don't find that to be too taxing. I also note that if you choose to go for `finiteset` instead of `unique` (as mentioned in `help @sym/unique`), it does not suffer from the same problem.

Comment: As I said before, please don’t post things in the answer box that don’t answer the question you posted here. Comments should go in the comment threads, and information to improve or expand on the answer should be edited right into the question itself. There is an [edit] link at the bottom of the question, right underneath the tags.

Comment: One of the package maintainers confirmed that this is a bug: https://github.com/cbm755/octsympy/issues/1047

Answer (score 1):

My workaround was the following code:

```
function un=mifUnique(rowcol)
  if isempty(rowcol)
    un=[];
  elseif
    ~isvector(rowcol)
    un=mitSetupError("un=mifUnique(rowcol): 'rowcol' has to be a vector.");
  else
    rowcol(end+1)=rowcol(1);
    un=unique(rowcol);
  endif
endfunction
```

*** EDIT: More simple and flexible is:

```
function unque=mifUnique(unque)
  if numel(unque) < 2
    return
  else
    unque=unique(unque);
  endif
endfunction
```

Not only vectors, but any dimensions get supported.

*** END_EDIT

Until now i didn't know the function finiteset. Thanks much!
But how can i use the finiteset to test  a array of syms without the eval-function?

```
finiteset ([a,a,b])
ans = (sym) {[a  a  b]}

fs=finiteset ([a,a,b](:))
fs = (sym)

   [a]
   [ ]
  {[a]}
   [ ]
   [b]

>> typeinfo (fs)
ans = class
```

That's not that what i want.

Edit: Sorry, i should have read the help on 'finteset' through to the end

On the other hand, if you *want* to make a set from the elements of
a matrix, first convert it to a cell array:
A = [1 x 1; 2 1 x];
finiteset(num2cell(A)).

Now i will testing, which method works faster. Will it post soon.

Comment: This on the other hand can be considered an answer.

Comment: Hi Cris, should i mark my question solved? If yes, how to do that?

Comment: No, you should not. I assume this is not the answer you are looking for. I only suggested that this could be seen as an answer, as opposed to the other stuff you posted as answers.

Comment: Of course you are right. I'm new here so I still have to learn. Thanks for the advice. The other answers have already been deleted.